# Multiple contacts being created

Tags: integration

We are experiencing an issue where multiple contacts are being created from an unknown source. It is so irritating to delete it manually everytime.

How can I find out where is it coming from.

Comment: Do you mean that when you create one Contact, another (unwanted) Contact is automatically created with you as the owner?

Comment: Maybe you can check directly the name of the user who created the contact ? ("Created by" field) If this cannot help, maybe you can provide us with some details about why you can't find the source and what you already tried ?